# Blank page on back-button (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following problem: When I use either the jQuery Mobile back-button or the changePage function of jQuery Mobile to return to the previous page it doesn't show any data on the page. All javascript gets executed but page remains empty..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem I faced when I was removing pages from the DOM via javascript to prevent the first page from sticking into the DOM.  All it would show was a blank page when clicking the back button.

Are you removing previous pages from the DOM in your javascript?

And when you say the page "remains empty", is it just the data within the content tags, or is nothing appearing on the page at all (including jquery mobile enhancement markup)?

You should post your changePage function here so that I and others can help you out.